# Joomla Canonical Url Wrong

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

My sites show as canonical ulr this:

which is wrong.
 I don't know how to fix it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks christoforos

Comment: You need to elaborate. What does it show where and what would you expect?

Comment: @user3154108 Sorry it seems to be my mistake. See my own answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my mistake.

In the Sef Component I had fill the canonical url with the wrong value.

Hope someone else find it helpful.